# 2 different passports with different surnames

Tags: passports, dual-nationality

I have an EU passport (German) in my married name and a South African Passport in my maiden name. I have applied for a new SA passport, but will not receive it in time for my intended trip to SA in Feb. I will book my ticket in my married name and use my German passport for ticketing. Will I encounter any problems with this as I have to enter SA on my SA passport (in maiden name)? I am worried as SA immigration would presumably be sent my EU passport details in advance of my arrival in SA.

Comment: It's a very common situation.  The standard approach is to bring both passports and a certified copy of your marriage certificate.

Answer (score 4):

**It's not a problem**: my sons have passports in two different names, and have traveled quite a bit with (almost) no problems.  At the end of the day the only thing that really matters is that **the name on your ticket should match the name on the passport you present at check-in**.

Immigration does not generally care about the name on the ticket you use to arrive or leave, or (in most countries)that you have multiple passports, it only cares that you have a passport/visa that allows entry into that country.  However, on the odd chance that you get pulled into secondary for detailed grilling, having a marriage certificate to prove that your two passports are the same person won't hurt.

Only once did we have a slight hiccup: we had booked a triangle ticket going Australia-Japan-USA-Australia, under my son's Japanese name, and we also used the Japanese passport to enter the US.  On leaving the US, however, we had to present his Australian passport (since the Japanese passport had no Oz visa), and the check-in agent was momentarily befuddled because it didn't match the name on the ticket.  But we presented the other passport, and this was sorted out in a few minutes.  In retrospect, we should have booked the entire journey on the 'home' passport, and only presented the Japanese passport at Japanese immigration.